# How can i define mutual css for all component in my project?

Tags: css

Currently, i join to project build UI lib with styled-component.
I will export Button component to my client project. How can i create 1 mutual class for all button in project from my lib.

sample css object:

```
button1-css {
    margin: 3px 0.5rem; 
    cursor: pointer;
    --another css
}
button2-css {
    margin: 3px 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    --another css
}
```

to

```
button-multual-css {
    margin: 3px 0.5rem; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
button1-css { 
    --another css
}
button1-css {
    --another css
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `,`? If I understand correctly, what you want is:

button1-css, button2-css {
    ....
}
No need to create an additional class

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.